# Why exactly does passing a closure from one class to another and calling it from the second class execute code from the first class?

Tags: php, class, lambda, scope, this

It's pretty difficult to come up with a title for this question but basically here is the code:

```
<?php

class Sub {
    protected $closure;

    public function setClosure($closure) {
        $this->closure = $closure;
    }

    public function callClosure() {
        $this->closure->__invoke();
    }

    protected function outcome() {
        echo 'calling from sub';
    }
}

class Main {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->sub = new Sub();
    }

    public function start() {
        $this->sub->setClosure(function() {
            $this->outcome();
        });

        $this->sub->callClosure();
    }

    protected function outcome() {
        echo 'calling from main';
    }
}

$main = new Main();
$main->start();
```

The outcome of it is `calling from main`. This is exactly what I want, however, since I'll be dealing with this behavior and I don't fully understand why it works this way I would like some clarification.

Before writing the code I was expecting it to call the `outcome` method from the `Sub` class, not from the `Main` class. Does the closure use `$this` from the scope from which it was defined? What if, for whatever reason, I want it to use `$this` from the scope it's being called from?

Comment: Because the closure needs to be [bound to the second class instance](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works properly and according to [php anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) manual because

> The parent scope of a closure is the function in which the closure was
>   declared (not necessarily the function it was called from)

In php this anonymous functions implemented as [Closure class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php). 
And as already [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) said when you create your closure inside your `Main` class you automatically get this bound object and this class scope.

> The “bound object” determines the value $this will have in the
>   function body and the “class scope” represents a class which
>   determines which private and protected members the anonymous function
>   will be able to access. Namely, the members that will be visible are
>   the same as if the anonymous function were a method of the class given
>   as value of the newscope parameter.

In your case this class is `Main` not `Sub`